# Having a trouble with efficiency of my method. Any advice?

Tags: java, performance, big-o

Two numbers n and m are called "friends" if the sum of the dividers of  n  is  m
and vice versa.

For example : if n = 200 and m = 284 than

1+2+4+5+10+11+20+22+44+55+110 = 284

1+2+4+71+142 = 220.

So the method needs to get a number K,
The method should return the number of pairs the are "Friends"

If K = 9000 than the method will return  5 since there are 5 pairs that are "Friends":

220,284

1184,1210

2620,2924

5020,5564

6232,6368

What is the most efficient running time in terms of big O ?

Comment: This is my method, the one I need to write. Looking for advice , the advice should be the running time in terms of Big O .

Comment: Well..To measure the running time you would need a method / algorithm to generate these numbers - some ways will be faster than others.. Have you come up with a way to generate these numbers?

Comment: I thought to start with a loop until reaching K 
and for each number from 1 to K, lets say a number N. I will call to a function that checks the sum of the number dividers. This will give me a number M. and then compares the sum  of the dividers of M to N. 
if there's a match then increment a variable for counting the number of pairs.

the function that will compare. will have running time of O(n)

Comment: Ok.. until now you have O(n) because you said "for each number from 1 to K". You are going through each number once. But this is not complete: how do you generate the divisors of your number N?

Comment: I meant O(K)

so total time will be  O(K^k)

Comment: Depending on the algorithm you are using for factorization and the one for building all divisors (combinations of prime factors) you might end up better than a worst case of O(n^n). I have not dealt with _sopfr_ calculations enough to have beckground in judging dependant complexity of exclusions (numbers that can not be part of a friends pairing and thus allow reducing complexity by a decent degree)

Comment: I will call for each number to the method that will check if a number from 1 to n/2  is a divider of n. and within this loop I will sum the dividers. and then I will get the sum which is a number M. so now I will check in another loop (but in the same method) the sum of the dividers of M

and at the end of the function I will compare the results

Comment: n is a generic notation, O(k) is pretty non-standard, but yes you're right :) What you could do is to go to sqrt(n) instead of n/2 and then i think you could say it becomes O(n*sqrt(n)) ?

Comment: So bruteforce...; you might adapt _sieve of eratosthenes_ for reducing number of unsuccessful checks (would help with identifying prime factors also). But it might pay to check for some more clever algorithm for identifying prime factors.

Comment: @Teo , you meant O(n^sqrt(n)) I  think

Comment: Finding amicable(friendly) pairs is a challenging job to do fast. You might dive into academic databases. Or if K is known and not too large you can find amicable pairs list on web.

Comment: @idan di, no, i meant multiplication.. Maybe this link helps: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/ Finding the divisors is called integer factorization - as others already mentioned, if you google a bit you will find other more efficient ways than checking if each number to sqrt(n) can be a divisor (this is "brute-force" because you are really checking each number) Same with iterating to K (the outer loop is also brute-force), maybe there's some better way to generate magic numbers.

Comment: @idan di It's n*n because.. Let's consider this code: x=0; for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {for (int j=0;j<N;j++) x++;} How much is x..

Comment: @Teo , I understand. 
about the exact runing time in terms of big O
I will run the loop for each number with the bound of sqrt(n)
so I got "big O" of :
sqrt(1)+sqrt(2)+...+sqrt(n)
And I dont know what it's exactly means in terms of big O

Comment: I *think* you can approximate it to an upper bound of O(n*sqrt(n)) unless maybe you find some formula for sqrt(1)+...+sqrt(n)

Comment: Well, maybe, just maybe, if we were to dive into uncharted, unconfirmed territory, if i would believe the 5th answer from here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241864/sum-of-square-roots-formula The upper bound would be a function of x^(2/3), so generically the whole thing would be O(n^(2/3)) but this is just guess & speculation based on an unconfirmed answer.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't tell you the whole algorithmic complexity for the best implementation I can break it down, at least for the brute force methodology if you implement a counter, so that when you adjust the factorising method you know what the new **O** value is

The first step: Cycle through numbers 0(or 1)-K this is **O(K)** and apply step 2 and 3 to them

The second step: Get the (sum) of the numbers divisors. This is **O(K)** if we calculate divisors by cycling through all of the numbers up to it.

The third step: Calculate if the sum of the divisors sum of divisors(That is a mouthful) is equal to the original number **O(K)**. If it is increment a counter.

The fourth step: output the counter variable **0(1)** time

So the overall algorithmic complexity of the brute force method is **O(K*2K)** = **O(K^2)**